# Two reverse proxy on one server, nginx

Tags: nginx

Is it possible?
I want know how would be work this config.

Is it Ok or not and why?

```
upstream one_proxy {
    ip_hash;

    server unix:/var/run/websocket-proxy.20000.sock max_fails=0;
    server unix:/var/run/websocket-proxy.20001.sock max_fails=0;
}
upstream two_proxy {
    ip_hash;
    server 1.2.3.4:1234;
}
server {
    server_name domain_name;
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;

    access_log off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://one_proxy;
    }
}
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:20003;
    access_log off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://two_proxy;
    }
}
```

Definitely config not complete but I think it look like good.

I didn't find examples with two reverse proxy on one nginx and I doubt.

If you have experience share it please )

Comment: It's OK, even if you put two proxy_pass in two location in the same server block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you know `nginx -t -c conf/your-custom-nginx.conf` command could test the configuration

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I knew this command. But I doubted. And I don't want to broke prod )

Comment: The config is all right,  just check if the logic is correct.